# Rails: Simple Form Custom Label Not Working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, simple-form

I'd like to create a custom label for a simple form field. For some reason, the below code isn't creating that label. It's still using the default label. I must be missing something easy.

`Simple Form 3.1`

```
<%= simple_form_for "#" do |f| %>
  <%= f.input :street, label: "Custom Label"  %>
  ...
<% end %>
```

How can I create a custom label for my inputs in Simple Form?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to use a label helper along with your input helper:

```
<%= simple_form_for "#" do |f| %>
   <%= f.label :street, 'Custom label' %>
   <%= f.input :street, as: :string, label: false %>
<% end %>
```

You can also directly specify input types ie. f.text_field - More info : http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html

Comment: Still not working. Now I have two 'Street' labels. Thanks for the response, btw!

Comment: What input type is f intended to be?   ie.  f.text_area -  consider f.input as psuedo code for whatever field type you desire.

Comment: It's supposed to be a text type.

Comment: Have edited the code to suit.  Let me know how it goes.

Comment: That made a label alright. I ended up modifying your code to keep the first f. line, then do `f.input :street, as: :string, label: false`. That kept all the styling and input types the same. If you want to update your code with my technique, I'm happy to select your answer.

Comment: Good stuff mate.  I will update my answer, your solution is quite concise.

Answer (score 1):

You can now pass a label as argument. So the syntax as shown in the question (from 2015) now works:

```
<%= f.input :street, label: "Custom Label"  %>
```

See [the "Usage" section of the readme](https://github.com/heartcombo/simple_form#usage).